# Django ORM case sensitive lookup returns case insensitive results

Tags: django, django-orm

I have file field on a model and want to find instance by file path.

```
>>> path
u'docs/grinbeta_1.pdf'
>>> DocFileVersion.objects.filter(file=path).values_list('file', flat=True)
[u'docs/grinbeta_1.pdf', u'docs/Grinbeta_1.pdf']
```

I expect the query to return only the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to the collation setting you are using in DATABASE configuration. Take a look at [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#id4)